# Flex 4.6 dropDownList selectedIndex value set?

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu, selectedindex

I am studying from the 'Flex in a week' tutorials and I have reached a point where they implement MVC model in Flex. All was well up until that point, but in the view they use a dropDownList to connect to a dataProvider and leave the selectedIndex undeclared (Defaults to -1). I (trying to be clever!) try to set the selectedIndex = 0 or 1 or any other number. But nothing happens, how could I do this?

Lesson details are here:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining/exercises/ex2_06.html

in my opinion the important bits of the code are:

Main app:

Array is created:

```
            [Bindable]
            private var employees:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
```

This array is populated with date from httpservice:

```
                for each (var emp:Object in employeeData) 
                {
                    employee = new Employee();
                    employee.firstName = emp.firstName;
                    employee.lastName = emp.lastName; 
                    employee.id = emp.id; 
                    employee.title = emp.title; 
                    employee.email = emp.email; 
                    employee.managerID = emp.managerID; 
                    employee.department = emp.department; 
                    employee.location = emp.location; 
                    employee.deskLocation = emp.deskLocation; 
                    employee.city = emp.city; 
                    employee.state = emp.state; 
                    employee.countryCode = emp.countryCode; 
                    employee.postalCode = emp.postalCode; 
                    employee.directDial = emp.directDial; 
                    employee.hireDate = emp.hireDate; 
                    employee.evaluation = emp.evaluation; 
                    employee.phone = emp.phone;
                    employees.addItem(employee);
                }
```

Passed to a custom component in array form:

```
    <components:VehicleRequestForm employees="{employees}"/>
```

This custom form captures it and puts in a dropDownList, but the selectedIndex doesn't appear to work, it still defaults to -1. How can I fix this? (all ideals appreciated):

```
        <s:FormItem label="Employee:">
            <s:DropDownList id="dropDownList"
                            dataProvider="{employees}"
                            labelField="lastName"
                            selectedIndex="1"/>
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="Office Phone:">
            <s:TextInput id="phone"
                         text="{dropDownList.selectedItem.phone}"/>
```

ex2_08_solutions.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="850"
               creationComplete="employeeService.send()" 
               xmlns:components="components.*">

    <!-- Exercise 2.08: Creating an ArrayCollection of value objects -->

    <!-- Styles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <fx:Style source="Styles.css"/>

    <!-- Script ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            import valueObjects.Employee;

            // variable declarations ------------------------------------

            [Bindable]
            private var employees:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            // getter/setters -------------------------------------------


            // helper methods -------------------------------------------


            // event handlers -------------------------------------------

            protected function employeeService_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                var employeeData:ArrayCollection = event.result.employees.employee;
                var employee:Employee;

                for each (var emp:Object in employeeData) 
                {
                    employee = new Employee();
                    employee.firstName = emp.firstName;
                    employee.lastName = emp.lastName; 
                    employee.id = emp.id; 
                    employee.title = emp.title; 
                    employee.email = emp.email; 
                    employee.managerID = emp.managerID; 
                    employee.department = emp.department; 
                    employee.location = emp.location; 
                    employee.deskLocation = emp.deskLocation; 
                    employee.city = emp.city; 
                    employee.state = emp.state; 
                    employee.countryCode = emp.countryCode; 
                    employee.postalCode = emp.postalCode; 
                    employee.directDial = emp.directDial; 
                    employee.hireDate = emp.hireDate; 
                    employee.evaluation = emp.evaluation; 
                    employee.phone = emp.phone;
                    employees.addItem(employee);
                }

            }

            protected function employeeService_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show(event.fault.faultString,"Fault Information");    
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- Declarations ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <fx:Declarations>

        <s:HTTPService id="employeeService"
                       url="http://adobetes.com/f45iaw100/remoteData/employees.xml"
                       result="employeeService_resultHandler(event)"
                       fault="employeeService_faultHandler(event)"/>

    </fx:Declarations>

    <!-- UI components ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <s:Label x="10" y="34" 
             width="690" height="40" 
             text="Employee Portal: Vehicle Request Form"
             styleName="titleHeader"/>

    <components:VehicleRequestForm employees="{employees}"/>

</s:Application>
```

VehicleRequestForm.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         creationComplete="init()">

    <!-- Styles ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->



    <!-- Script ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            // import statements ----------------------------------------

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.CalendarLayoutChangeEvent;

            // variable declarations ------------------------------------

            [Bindable]
            public var employees:ArrayCollection;

            // getter/setters -------------------------------------------


            // helper methods -------------------------------------------


            // event handlers -------------------------------------------

            private function dateChangeHandler(event:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show('You have selected ' + event.target.selectedDate.toDateString());

                if ((event.target.id == "returnDate") && (pickupDate.selectedDate > returnDate.selectedDate)) 
                {
                    Alert.show("Pickup date must be scheduled before return date.");
                }

                if ((event.target.id == "pickupDate") && (pickupDate.selectedDate > returnDate.selectedDate) && (returnDate.selectedDate != null)) 
                {
                    Alert.show("Pickup date must be scheduled before return date.")
                }

            }

            private function init():void
            {
                pickupDate.addEventListener(CalendarLayoutChangeEvent.CHANGE, dateChangeHandler);
                returnDate.addEventListener(CalendarLayoutChangeEvent.CHANGE, dateChangeHandler);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- Declarations ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <!-- UI components ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

    <s:Form x="10" y="70">

        <s:FormItem label="Employee:">
            <s:DropDownList id="dropDownList"
                            dataProvider="{employees}"
                            labelField="lastName"
                            selectedIndex="1"/>
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="Office Phone:">
            <s:TextInput id="phone"
                         text="{dropDownList.selectedItem.phone}"/>
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="Mobile Phone:">
            <s:TextInput id="mobilePhone"/>
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormHeading label="Dates Requested"/>

        <s:FormItem label="Pickup Date:">
            <mx:DateChooser id="pickupDate"/>
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem label="Return Date:">
            <mx:DateChooser id="returnDate"/>
        </s:FormItem>

        <s:FormItem>
            <s:Button id="submitButton" 
                      label="Submit Request"/>
        </s:FormItem>

    </s:Form>

</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set `selectedIndex` to an index that is not in `dataProvider`. When your `DropdownList` is instantiated, `dataProvider` is an empty collection, so 1 is not a valid selected index.

Try to set your `selectedIndex` after you populate the collection. You may need to do this in `callLater` (as soon as data is usually processed not immediately, but at the end of the frame. For some components this is very important, for others you can ignore it).

If you just need to force selection, try to set `requireSelection` to `true`.

**update**(how to use callLater)

```
protected function employeeService_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
            //...populating dataprovider

            callLater(function():void{
                if(dropDownList.dataProvider.length > wantedIndex){
                    dropDownList.selectedIndex=wantedIndex;
                }else{
                    Alert.show('can\'t select necessary index!','error')
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: requireSelection hard coded it to "0" and gives me no control over which one to select. Can you show me how you would use callLater? I have looked at the adobe website and it isn't clear to me how to use it in this instance.

Comment: It seems to me an override of commitProperties would be a better place to do this (coupled with a flag that lets you know that the data has changed, so the selected index needs to change as well).

Comment: added usage of calllater.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<s:DropDownList requireSelection="true" />
```

If true, a data item must always be selected in the control. If the value is true, the selectedIndex property is always set to a value between 0 and (dataProvider.length - 1).